# What to do with questions too old for migration

Tags: discussion, migration

I have just run into [this question at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7745463/1469208). As comment below states, this question fits perfectly to the *Programmers* and in the same time is a nearly perfect example of an off-topic question at SO (chit-chat discussion like question). However, I can't flag it to be migrated to Programmes. It is too old.

How to handle such questions? I don't think, it should remain at SO only cause it's to old for migration.