# Why too old questions can't be migrated?

Tags: discussion, migration

Following [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/248460/189165).
I have just run into [this question at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7745463/1469208). It seems to be fitting perfectly to the *Programmers*, it is a nearly perfect example of an off-topic question at SO  and yet, it can't be migrated, because it is too old.

How and why came with the idea of questions being to old for migration? What is the reason behind this? If some questions fits badly *here* and fits perfectly *there*, what value do we have from blocking their migration only because of their age?

*Note: This question is not a duplicate of [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160726/189165). I don't want to know, why questions too old for a migration, are migrated even so. I want to know, what is the idea in marking question as too old for migration, at all.*

Comment: Because it is a waste of time and the question of what to do with all the votes accumulated comes up time and again. See the post I duped you to where the decision was taken.